# can't change autoincremet variable in mariadb

Tags: mariadb, auto-increment

I have problem with auto_increment in mariadb. I have 4 galera nodes. but my auto_increment_increment variable is 4.. Can I change dynamic? Is there any problem in big systems when I have billion or more items in table..

```
MariaDB [kohadata]> show variables like '%auto%';
+------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                | Value |
+------------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment     | 4     |
| auto_increment_offset        | 2     |
| autocommit                   | ON    |
| automatic_sp_privileges      | ON    |
| innodb_autoextend_increment  | 8     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode     | 2     |
| innodb_stats_auto_update     | 1     |
| sql_auto_is_null             | OFF   |
| wsrep_auto_increment_control | ON    |
| wsrep_retry_autocommit       | 1     |
+------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you want to make it bigger? Or smaller? Do you always write to just one node or do you balance the writes across the cluster?